# How do you change the user in Subclipse on Mac?

Tags: macos, svn, subclipse

I did a checkout using a temp username and password yesterday.

Now that I have a new username and password, how can I change my credentials without having to delete my checkout and recheckout?

Comment: In ordinary Subversion the credentials are stored in `~/.subversion/` and are not specific to a given working copy ('checkout'). I don't know whether this is true for Subclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** this will work.

Disconnect the project from SVN then reconnect with your new credentials.

Comment: Hi Chris, how do I disconnect the project from SVN? I literally just installed subclipse last night and still trying to get my way around it.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is a necro thread, but if you delete the server credentials at:

```
%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\
```

And then the .keyring file at:

```
\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime
```

You will be prompted for username / password with the next svn command you attempt.

Comment: We even have rewards for [necromancy](http://superuser.com/badges/17/necromancer) on this site, so don't worry about it ;) You should have read the question though: The user has a Mac, which means he's running Mac OS X, not Windows.